# Transforming list values of a map to their mean value by an attribute

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-8

I start with `Map<String,List<Rating>>`. Rating has a method `int getValue()`.

I want to end up with `Map<String,Integer>` where the Integer value is the mean value of all the `Rating.getValue()` values grouped by the key from the original `Map<String,List<Rating>>`.

I would be pleased to receive some ideas on how to tackle this.

Answer (score 4):

Performing aggregation operations on a collection of integers can be done with `IntStream` methods. In your case, `average` seems like the right method to use (notice that it returns a `Double`, not `Integer`, which seems like a better choice).

What you want is to convert each entry of the original map to an entry in a new map, where the key remains the same, and the value is the average of the values of the `List<Rating>` elements. Generating the output map can be done using a `toMap` `Collector`.

```
Map<String,Double> means =
    inputMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                      e->e.getValue()
                                          .stream()
                                          .mapToInt(Rating::getValue)
                                          .average()
                                          .orElse(0.0)));
```

Comment: I think it couldn't be implemented any better!

Comment: @Eran, you are right it was actually a Double that I wanted. I'll now see if your example can pass my existing tests and report back.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using [`averagingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) as next:

```
Map<String, Double> means =
    map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(
                    Collectors.averagingInt(Rating::getValue)
                )
            )
        );
```

---

Assuming that you would like to go a little bit further and you need more statistics like `count`, `sum`, `min`, `max` and `average`, you could consider using [`summarizingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) instead, you will then get [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) instead of a `Double`

```
Map<String, IntSummaryStatistics> stats =
    map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(
                    Collectors.summarizingInt(Rating::getValue)
                )
            )
        );
```